# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'open' was called on null. in razorpay

Tags: flutter

```
My razor pay coding 



final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

final options = {
  "description": 'Thanks for placing order!',
  "image": baseImage,
  "currency": "INR",
  "key": " rzp_live_vwdPSYlBoyrXul", // your Key Id from Razorpay dashboard
  "amount": total_amt,
  "name": 'Good way',
  "prefill": {
    "email": '',
    "contact": prefs.getString("user_name"),
    "name": ''
  },
};
_razorpay.open(options);
```

If i click pay
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'open' was called on null it coming like this

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the error says you are trying to call the method "open" on a variable which has null as value.
You need to debug where and how you define the _razorpay variable, it might get stuck somwhere, or you just forgot to define/instantiate it

Answer (score 0):

`_razorpay` can be null here.

on Your pay button you can check if `_razorpay` is null or has value.

```
if(_razorpay != null) {
 //Procced to pay
}
```